# Stacking 5 list items under each other

Tags: html, css

I got a template from themeforest. There are some boxes near the bottom of the website (the ones with delivery worldwide etc)

When I make it smaller they dissapear, does anybody know how I can make them stack under each other?

This is the template: http://pixelgeeklab.com/demo/wordpress/flatize/?page_id=579

It's about this part:

```
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <ul class="wp-ads">
            <li><i class="fa fa-plane"></i><strong>Delivery worldwide</strong>See all conditions</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i><strong>30 days returns</strong>For a smooth shopping</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><strong>0123 456 789</strong>Contact Customer</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-lock"></i><strong>30 days returns</strong>For a smooth shopping</li>
            <li><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i><strong>Shopping Guide</strong>Contact Customer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it dissapears is because it is inside `<section class="section-element hidden-xs">` so it's `display` is `none` when your `width < 767px`.
You should remove the class `hidden-xs`.

And add this css code.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .wp-ads li {
         background: #1abc9c;
         color: white;
         display: block; 
         float: none;
         overflow: hidden;
         padding: 20px 0 20px 25px;
         width: 20%;
    }
}
```

You may want to increase the `width` when your view is smaller.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .wp-ads li {
         background: #1abc9c;
         color: white;
         display: block; 
         float: none;
         overflow: hidden;
         padding: 20px 0 20px 5%;
         width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it, I'll accept your answer in 3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the css, if I understand you right, you simply want to disable the floating of the li elements and make them appear as a stack, right?

Have a look at template.css about line 1497:

```
.wp-ads li {
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 25px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

change it to

```
.wp-ads li {
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* float: left; */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 25px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want but unfortunately that didn't do it. The boxes become really small and overlap each other.

Comment: They only seem to overlap, they are stacked directly to each other. change it to width:100%; and margin-top: 5px; should work